# How do I read yaml file using javascript with framwork vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yaml

I have Vuejs app need to read data from YAML file in the root directory, so I google it and then find some useful package on Github [this link](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) I know they are created just for Nodejs as backend, but they have a way to work with a browser in their documentation I follow it but it's not loading my YAML file in the root directory it's just print the file name of YAML `../../example.yaml`.

example.yaml

```yaml
greeting: hello
name: world
```

page.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="doIt">create</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
const jsyaml = require('js-yaml');

export default {
  methods:{
    doIt(){
      var doc = jsyaml.load('../../example.yaml');
      console.log("your content yaml file is : ", doc);    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

So my question how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsyaml.load` expects a *YAML string*, not a path or URL. If you're using webpack, you can use [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) to import the file as a string for use in your app.

Comment: perfect thank you, I am a starter to vuejs, so I did notice there is away on the webpack package that will achieve my task, thanks a lot!